# Export data to excel from drupal

Tags: excel, drupal, export

I need to export all my users with their webform submitted data to excel file.I can export users, but how do this with related webforms I dont now. Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('"', sd.data, '"' )), ', "',u.uid, '","', u.name, '", "', u.mail,'"') from webform_submitted_data sd JOIN webform_submissions s ON s.sid = sd.sid JOIN users u ON u.uid = s.uid GROUP by s.sid LIMIT 1 INTO OUTFILE '/Users/nandersen/Downloads/users.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '' ENCLOSED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

You need to group concatenate the webform data, which is multiple rows but one column with the user data which is in mutiple columns but one row.  So by concatenating the data separately and grouping by the submission id, you can get the data you need.

Will output something like this:

```
"Nate","Andersen","nate@test.com","123 Atlanta Avenue","Nederland","Texas","12345","4095496504","safe_key4","safe_key6","safe_key2","09/07/1989", "69","oknate", "nate@test.com"
```